# The sound of a moving tree trunk

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs

When it's windy out as the wind is blown against a large standing tree, its trunk moves and makes a noise similar to that creaking noise that a door or a floorboard in a house makes.

Do we use *creak* to refer to this noise in this case, or what is the typical way of describing this sound?

Comment: Does a living tree trunk actually *creak*? Floorboards and doors creak because two surfaces rub against each other, but if any parts of the trunk itself were *rubbing against "each other"* I'd have thought that would mean the structure of the tree was breaking down. *Branches* would rub together sometimes, though.

Comment: I think [*creak* is the correct word.](http://www.theanswerbank.co.uk/Animals-and-Nature/Question380662.html)

Comment: Yes, I think *creak* is a fine word for this.  Having spent much of my youth running around in the woods I can tell you that they do creak in the wind.  *Groan* is also another fine word to use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*[Creak](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/creak#Verb)* (“To make a prolonged sharp grating or squeaking sound, as by the friction of hard substances”) is the most-commonly-applicable term for sounds made by parts of trees moving in the wind rubbing together.  An answer to [Question380662](http://www.theanswerbank.co.uk/Animals-and-Nature/Question380662.html) at theanswerbank.co.uk explains fairly well one of the sources of creaking:

> ... when the wind blows, and its force moves the tree, the tree does not move uniformly.
>
> As a living organism, a tree is in a constant state of development, so the fibres in its trunk and branches are all at different stages of development - some are fully mature and dry, some are new and full of sap. As the trunk and branches move, different areas of the wood respond differently. Some move a good deal, some don't move at all.
>
> As different fibres with different tensile strengths which are in close proximity react - or not - to the force of the wind, they rub against each other with friction. This is what causes the distinctive 'creaking' noise when a tree is bending in the wind.

Another common source of creaking is that different large limbs of a tree may curve and cross each other, thus making creaking noises as the wind moves the limbs independently.

*[Crack](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crack#Verb)*, *[crackle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crackle#Verb)*, *[groan](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/groan#Verb)*, and *[boom](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boom#Verb)* are other verbs commonly used to describe tree sounds.  Cracking and crackling often occur during cold snaps that freeze some of the tree's sap.  *Boom* is used several times in a  [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/05/15/nyregion/ailing-trees-sound-a-warning-before-falling.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0) article about New Yorkers injured by trees or limbs falling on them.  The article incidentally mentions some of the noises that occurred before the incidents; for example:

> Mrs. Berger’s was among at least 10 lawsuits in recent years that have raised questions about whether more diligent tree care by the city might have prevented the crack — or creak or boom — and the death or injury that it brought.

Answer (score 4):

In the right context, you might be able to use *groan*.

Comment: Interesting. Any online examples?

Comment: @Manoochehr: Sure; there are [lots of them](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22trees%20groaned%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1920,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en).